# GitHub API: get billing quota reset date

Tags: api, github-api, github-actions, billing, quota

Is there a GitHub API I can use to retrieve the number of days X in

> GitHub Actions
>
> Included minutes quota resets in X days

which you can find on the https://github.com/settings/billing page?

[image: billing quota]

Performing the following API call

```
# GITHUB_TOKEN with "Update ALL user data" permission
curl \
  -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/users/$GITHUB_USER/settings/billing/actions
```

I get all info except for the billing period expiration date:

```
{
  "total_minutes_used": 228,
  "total_paid_minutes_used": 0,
  "included_minutes": 2000,
  "minutes_used_breakdown": {
    "UBUNTU": 228
  }
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Would https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/246 help in the near future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out the *"number of days left in the billing cycle"* can be retrieved from the `/users/<user>/settings/billing/shared-storage` endpoint.

E.g.

```
curl \
  -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/users/$GITHUB_USER/settings/billing/shared-storage
```

returns

```
{
  "days_left_in_billing_cycle": 5,
  "estimated_paid_storage_for_month": 0,
  "estimated_storage_for_month": 0
}
```

Comment: Here's a script to retrieve all data about user billing: https://gist.github.com/horothesun/cb799c61a983a17c4aff68d9d413c4bf